# How to find Difference Time Between two record

Tags: sql, oracle

i Get some Problem with SQL , 
the problem is find the Difference between two record not in the same row .
i take picture of the Excel sheet to illustrate what i mean .
i need to find the difference between the recoed n and n+1  , one by one .

[image: EXCEL SHEET]

Comment: What have you tried? A tip: create a "Row Number" column in a CTE, and then self join the table on the "row number" of one side equal to the "row number" + 1 on another

Comment: Is there any other column in this sheet how do you determine the order of dates ???

Comment: i sorting the column by date only , yes the are a lot of column , this was a sample only

Comment: CTE abbreviation of what ?

Comment: Common Table Expressions. Did the System Administrator block access to google at you work?

Comment: No it is legal to Enter the google !

Comment: look at analytic functions.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `lag()` function:

```
select t.*,
       (t.admission_date_time - lag(t.admission_date_time) over (order by t.admission_date_time
       ) as diff
from table t;
```

This will fetch the value from the previous row.